# Loop all elements within an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, push

I am trying to create a new array which is a result of an old array which loops within itself and push all the elements to the new array starting from the giving index till it matches the length of old array.

**Example**

Old array `['yellow', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'white', 'orange', 'black']`

User enter any color name that is within the array like `white`

Expected output `['white', 'orange', 'black', 'yellow', 'red', 'green', 'blue']`

```js
function find_all_color() {
  var input = prompt("Enter any color");
  var colorArr = ['yellow', 'red','green', 'blue','white','orange', 'black']
  var arrIndex = colorArr.indexOf(input);
  var newArr = []
  for (let i = arrIndex; i <colorArr.length; i++) {
    newArr.push(colorArr[i])
    }     console.log(newArr)

}

 find_all_color(); // output - ['white', 'orange', 'black']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to create 2 shallow copies of your original array. You don't have to loop through your shallow copies, you can just use ES6 [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) assignment to merge those arrays

```js
var colorArr = ['yellow', 'red','green', 'blue','white','orange', 'black'];
var arrIndex = colorArr.indexOf('white');
var newArr = [...colorArr.slice(arrIndex), ...colorArr.slice(0, arrIndex)];

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want?

The first item is the item passed as entry in the sortListOfColors function. All the other items are the following until the end of an array and then all the items starting from the first item in input array and until the input entry index.

```js
const sortListOfColors = (input, entry) => [...input.slice(input.indexOf(entry)), ...input.slice(0, input.indexOf(entry))]


console.log(sortListOfColors(['yellow', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'white', 'orange', 'black'], 'white')) // ['white', 'orange', 'black', 'yellow', 'red', 'green', 'blue']
```